# If else statement using raster calculator or con arctoolbox in arcmap

Tags: raster, arcmap

based on this equation image, i'm trying to run the equation using raster calculator for raster image. The equation that I wrote was like this:
Float(SEI-NIR)== Con(NIR>=NDWI, SEI-NDWI)
but it was error.
[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDWny.png)

The results should threshold the image on which area has shadow

Comment: Not really a coding question, so you could have more luck at gis.stackexchange.com. I would seem to me that you would do `Con(NIR >= NDWI, SEI-NIR, SEI-NDWI)`